# R apply formula with two input variables

Tags: r, formula, apply

I have the following lapply formula that works for y = a fixed value (e.g. 0.06), how can i update it so that y can be a vector or list?

```
grp_constraint_min <- function(x,y) {
  group_constraintxxx(score, index = c(as.matrix(t(x$id))), dir = ">=", rhs = y)
}
consts2 <- do.call("rbind",lapply(data,grp_constraint_min, y = 0.06))
```

I've tried using `mapply` but keep getting errors, i'd like to have a vector for y such that for each value of x the equivalent y is used, rather than each y for each x: e.g. x1:y1, x2:y2... etc rather than x1:y1, x1:y2 etc.

Here is the code for 'data' and wgt_min which is what I'd like to be able to set rhs = to.

```
by_group <- split(df, df$SubGroup)
data <- lapply(by_group, '[',5)
wgt_min <- as.matrix(unlist(lapply(lapply(by_group, '[',4), sum))) - 0.025
```

So, in the above example what im trying to do is set a min weight for each subgroup (current weight - 2.5%) to pass through my formula which is used to create a constraint.

If its helpful the `data.frame data`:

```
df <- data.frame(Group=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), each=4),
                 SubGroup=c('A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'A.1', 'B.1', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'B.2', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'C.2', 'C.2', 'D.1', 'D.2', 'D.3', 'D.4'),
                 score=round(runif(16, 0, 1),2),
                 wgt=rep(1/16,16),
                 id=1:16)

score <- as.matrix(t(df$score))
```

Comment: I would think `mapply(FUN = grp_constraint_min, x = data, y = wgt_min, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` would work (wrap in `do.call` as needed). But I can't test because I don't have the `group_constraintxxx` function. What did you try, and what didn't work about it? You say you got errors, what were they?

Comment: Thank you, what you suggested has worked for me. I had tried the same function but without the `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and was getting this error "Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : Numbers of columns of matrices must match."